# VBA - Navigating HTML table with IF function

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm at the tail end of a project and have stumbled upon my final hurdle.  I have a set of movies in an excel sheet that I am looking up in BoxOfficeMojo.com and scraping a bunch of data from.

My problem can be summarized using the movie "Sing" as an example.  When I I search for that title I am directed to this webpage: http://www.boxofficemojo.com/search/?q=sing.  Right now the code I have to navigate to the movie-specific page is as follows:

```
 'open title page in box office
        Set Doc = objIE.Document
        Set oResult = Doc.getElementById("body").getElementsByTagName("a")
        For Each Element In oResult
            If Element.outerHTML Like "*/movies/?id=*" Then
                Set myLink = Element
                Exit For
            End If
        Next Element

        objIE.Navigate myLink
```

That code only navigates to the first movie link, which is not the one I want.  I'd like to only click on a link IF the "lifetime gross" column DOES NOT say "n/a".  Ideally something like this would work (new code in the IF function):

```
'open title page in box office
        Set Doc = objIE.Document
        Set oResult = Doc.getElementById("body").getElementsByTagName("a")
        For Each Element In oResult
            If Element.outerHTML Like "*/movies/?id=*" And Element.Offset(0, 2).innerText <> "n/a" Then
                Set myLink = Element
                Exit For
            End If
        Next Element

        objIE.Navigate myLink
```

This does not work though.  Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?  thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looping through each table until you find the correct one, and then looping through each row until you find one that meets your criteria.

```
Dim HTMLTable As Object
Dim i As Long

'Loop through each table to find the right one
For Each HTMLTable In Doc.getElementsByTagName("table")
    If Left(HTMLTable.Rows(0).Cells(0).innerText, 11) = "Movie Title" Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next HTMLTable

If Not HTMLTable Is Nothing Then 'table found
    For i = 1 To HTMLTable.Rows.Length - 1 'loop through each row and check gross column
        If HTMLTable.Rows(i).Cells(2).innerText <> "n/a" Then 'found row
            Set myLink = HTMLTable.Rows(i).Cells(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0) 'get link
            myLink.Click 'click link
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
Else 'table not found
    MsgBox "The table was not found.", vbExclamation
End If
```

If you're using early binding, you can declare `HTMLTable` as follows...

```
Dim HTMLTable As MSHTML.HTMLTable
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey @domenic - for some reason this code only works part of the time.  When I step through it manually it seems to work just fne, but when I run it through automatically it often times navigates to the wrong page.  Any ideas why?  I can past my entire code somewhere if you'd like

Comment: Sometimes more time is needed for the page to load.  Try waiting a few seconds before assigning the document from `IE` to your variable `Doc`.  So just before `Set Doc = objIE.Document`, add `Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))`.